# Create a raster with georeferenced information in R

Tags: raster, r, georeferencing

Referring to my previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/generating-visually-appealing-density-heat-maps-in-r), how do I "geocode"/convert - using R - a generated raster image to a format that can be shown as a layer on a map? In short, I'm aiming to recreate the results of the commercial [SpatialKey](http://www.spatialkey.com/industry-solutions/sales-marketing/details/increase-customer-satisfaction/) ([screenshot](http://www.giscafe.com/magazine/images/20091005/SpatialKey2L.jpg)) software.

I'm using a GeoServer instance to host the data for the maps, but how can I incorporate the required projection and coordinate info into the image so it will align correctly with its true geographical position. The density heatmap was produced using spatial data.

Comment: As this is solely a programming question this isn't really on topic. Have you looked at the spatstat package information and the short course pdf to see if it is covered there? I'm sure this has come up before, and a quick google search brings up [this relevant R-help answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2011-July/012202.html). I wouldn't be surprised if more direct solutions exist as well with some more searching.

Comment: How have you made the generated raster image? Is it coming from another application, or made within R?

Comment: It's generated within R using the image() function.

Comment: x has unequal horizontal and vertical resolutions. Such data cannot be stored in arc-ascii format My x has 4684, 1950 dimension, it complains about the resolution. I made it the same though. Buggy

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The raster package lets you create arbitrary rasters (size, projection) or use existing objects, like matrices; you can then assign projections & extents . Your `image()` function takes a matrix argument which can be used directly:

```
library(raster)    
## Create a matrix with random data & use image()
xy <- matrix(rnorm(400),20,20)
image(xy)

# Turn the matrix into a raster
rast <- raster(xy)
# Give it lat/lon coords for 36-37°E, 3-2°S
extent(rast) <- c(36,37,-3,-2)
# ... and assign a projection
projection(rast) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
plot(rast)
```

You can then use `writeRaster()` with any number of formats, e.g.

```
writeRaster(rast, "~/myraster.asc", format = "ascii")
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of different ways, but taking a stab that you want to use open-source tools on Windows I can suggest 3 options:

1. Use gdal_translate tool in [GDAL](https://gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) (open-source geo-raster manipulation library). You probably need the `-gcp pixel line easting northing elevation` parameter where pixel and line is x / y on the raster ([http://www.gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723070206/http://gdal.org:80/gdal_datamodel.html)) and easting / northing the geographic coordinates. You'll also have to specify a projection with `-a_srs srs_def`
2. Use the [r bindings](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) to GDAL and do the same thing
3. An easier "GUI" way might be to follow this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20180905221202/http://geo.distortions.net:80/2010/11/georeferencing-with-gdal-17-and-qgis-16.html) and use QGIS with GDAL. The disadvantage of this is you have to set up both QGIS and GDAL if you haven't already.

I would look carefully at the dependencies of each bit of software you need before going down whichever route you choose.